# How much money do you need to live in the US for half a year?

Tags: united-states, cost-of-living

I want to live in the US especially in California more specifically Burbank as an internship but I have no idea how much money am I gonna need to spend because I live in Japan. So I hope I could get reply from anyone who lives in California. Lets say..

- I will rent a home(for half a year)or maybe there's a better way?
- a few meal is ok.I'll have two meals a day
- I don't know how the tax system works... hope you could give me a lesson
- pen or paper,books or another stuff should be included too
- I want make it in reasonable way so if there's some tips,please tell me!
  Like "you're gonna have to use laundromat every time. Once in a week is preferable"

Comment: All anyone can say from this is "it depends".  You could start by looking at e.g. Craigslist for apartment & house rentals near where you plan to live.  Food costs depend on whether you eat out a lot, or cook yourself.  For the latter, you can probably find on-line grocery ads from the area.  (Note that prices at different supermarkets can vary quite a bit.)  You'll also need to consider the cost (and time) of transportation.  Another thought: If it's a fairly large company, it may have a web site for interns with cost info &c.

Answer (score 1):

So really "it depends". Are you going to live alone, or have a roommate? What will you do for transportation? One thing you can do it look at university web sites in the area and look at their estimates for monthly living expenses in the area. Not that you will be enrolling in a university, just that those web sites can give you a good idea of living expenses in that part of California.

An example site for Glendale (near Burbank) with additional links for more information can be found here:

https://www.glendale.edu/apply/international-students/off-campus-housing-homestays

As you can see, costs vary depending on your needs.